# using router-link in single File Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

i am stuck in router in my single file component, i am trying to include another component in single file component like i have named thirdtemplate.vue as my SFC and i include another component in it using Vue.component(“newTemplate”,{template:"…"}) as i have shown the example downwards in this post.i need to use router-link in my newTemplate component so that it calls the template of component newTemplate.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h4>hello this is from thirdTemplate</h4>
    <router-link to="/secondTemplate">Go to secondTemplate</router-link>
    <router-link to="/thirdTemplate">Go to thirdTemplate</router-link>
    <newtemplate></newtemplate>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
Vue.component("newtemplate", {
  template: "<template><div><button>hello</button></div></template>"
});

module.exports = {
  name: "thirdTemplate",
  methods: {},
  components: {}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this code to main.js where new Vue constructor is defined

```
Vue.component("newtemplate", {
  template: "<template><div><button>hello</button></div></template>"
});
```

And configure your router for first template and second template

Comment: as a programmer i was thinking why to make mutiple .Vue file for each component why not to include all my necessary components in single file.example:- if i want to make a product table in which i have components as product-list,product-details,add-product,edit-product .why i cannot include my all components in one if i include all component in main.js the file will go so long,and if i make another file .vue it will bulk up my project.

Comment: please tell me if i am wrong somewhere since i am new to Vue @chans

Comment: In vue.js components are nothing but template or you can call it as a container, where you can write all the HTML css JavaScript for a particular view(UI), having a separate components in each .vue files is clean approach and register only the main components in main.js and register child components inside any .vue files wherever you use

Comment: There are 7 ways to define a component in Vue https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d

Comment: @Ajharali have you tried with multiple components files?

Comment: yes, but not able to use that component when i want to use thats why now i am doing simple thing as vuejs documentation says make SFC for each component and import it wherever you want since i am a beginner the above question took me too long to find the appropriate answer. thanks for your reply@chan

Comment: Do accept and upvote, if this fix resolves your issue